# Stuck on Number Theory Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like help with getting started with the following problem:

Suppose $a$, $b$, and $c$ are relatively prime integers that satisfy $\frac{a}{b+c} = 2$ and $\frac{b}{a+c} = 3$. What is the value of $|c|$?

I know that $a$ must be even and therefore $b$ and $c$ must be odd (otherwise they wouldn't be relatively prime). I have tried substituting and rearranging but haven't been able to solve for $c$. Any hints would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Pieces of hints in chronological order:

> The two equations can be rewritten as $a=2b+2c$ and $b=3a+3c$. Substituting the second equation into the first yields $a=6a+8c$, and this becomes $5a+8c=0$.

> Since $a,c$ are all integers, we have that $5 \mid 8c$ which gives us $5 \mid c$. Thus, the smallest possible value for $|c|$ is $5$.

> Upon substituting $c=5$, we get that $a=-8$, and $b=-9$. These clearly are pairwise coprime, and since $|c| \leq 5$ and we have found an example for $|c| = 5$, we are done and thus the minimum value for $|c|$ is  $5$.

> The solution has no trouble with a $0$ denominator as $-9+5 \neq 0$ and $-8+5 \neq 0$.